# аналог egrep для структурного поиска/замены (с учетом грамматики)

Tags: текст, grep, грамматика

Подскажите есть ли готовые утилиты, аналогичные egrep: пакетная утилита
позволяющая выполнять поиск/замену/трансформацию в текстовых файлах с разметкой (с учетом грамматики) ?

Предполагается интерпретатор некоторого скриптового язычка, позволяющего описать наборы правил с использованием регулярок, грамматик, унификации шаблонов и некоторых выражений, позволяющих при срабатывании правила выполнять модификации в исходном файле, и генерировать новые файлы.

Например пробежаться по проекту, построить таблицу идентификаторов, посчитать статистику по коду, сгенерировать произвольный Makefile на основе зависимостей файлов, сгенерировать шаблон документации для кода, выполнить замену идентификатора по всему проекту, переформатировать код и т.п.

PS: или как называются алгоритмы для написания такой утилиты

Answer (score 1):

Пробуй ack

С оффициального сайта:

"ack 2.18 is a tool like grep, optimized for programmers

Designed for programmers with large heterogeneous trees of source code, ack is written purely in portable Perl 5 and takes advantage of the power of Perl's regular expressions."

ack 2.18 инструмент схожий grep, оптимизированный для программистов

Разработан для прграммистов с развлетвоенными деревьями исходеого кода, ack полностью написан на портируемом Perl 5, и перенял всю силу регулярных выражений Perl'а.

https://beyondgrep.com/

Comment: Переведи на русский.
Translate to Russian.

Comment: Добавил перевод описания.

Answer (score 0):

The TXL Programming Language
https://www.txl.ca/

TXL is a programming language specifically designed for manipulating and experimenting with
programming language notations and features using source to source transformation.
While TXL was originally designed to support experiments in programming language design, it has proven much
more widely applicable. It has been used in a range of applications in programming languages, software engineering,
database applications, structured documents, web technology and artificial intelligence among many others, and with a
range of programming languages.

Список мануалов с алгоритмами, теорией, и т.п. доступны вот в этой статье: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167642306000669